# Load/sync multiple small mysql databases to one larger one

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I am looking trying to load/sync multiple small mysql databases into a big mysql warehouse using Mysql binlogs and Apache Nifi. everything works good, but thinking about scalability and minimum data loss, I am trying to introduce Kafka to store messages and consume them. Can someone help me how can I use kafka in this context, How kafka could receive messages from mysql bin logs ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Debezium](https://debezium.io/) or [maxwell](https://github.com/zendesk/maxwell) to read data to Kafka.

NiFi is not required, but has its own [`CaptureChangeMySQL` processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-cdc-mysql-nar/1.19.1/org.apache.nifi.cdc.mysql.processors.CaptureChangeMySQL/index.html) that you could forward to `ProduceKafka`.

You'd still need a Kafka consumer to read the data in order to write to the destination table. The more hops you introduce, the larger chances for networking delays and introduce possible data transfer loss.

NiFi on its own is scalable. So is Kafka. They are not competing tools.

Comment: Thank You @onecricketeer. I am currently using Nifi's Capturechange Mysql processor (by using Binlogs and GTID enabled) which is working good.  My current flow is like source mysqlDB -> Nifi -> small transformations -> destination DB. As I am using GTID, when a job flow failed, all the changes happen ed during the failure were picked up when i restart again. Given above context, I want to understand is Kafka really needed in this usecase or its completely not needed ?

Comment: Using Kafka and associated tools mentioned will allow you to use the data outside of Nifi, directly from Kafka clients, if that's important to you

Comment: Okay. my current use case doesn't need data outside Nifi. My intention is to ask if at all any messaging broker (like kafka) is needed in this scenario ? or I can rely completely on Nifi and mysql GTIDs to ensure no data loss and restartabilities.

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't use Nifi, only kafka